# How to register event with useEffect hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am following a Udemy course on how to register events with hooks, the instructor gave the below code:

```js
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState('');

  const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;

    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      setUserText(`${userText}${key}`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
```

Now it works great but I'm not convinced that this is the right way. The reason is, if I understand correctly, on each and every re-render, events will keep registering and deregistering every time and I simply don't think it is the right way to go about it.

So I made a slight modification to the `useEffect` hooks to below

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);
  };
}, []);
```

By having an empty array as the second argument, letting the component to only run the effect once, imitating `componentDidMount`. And when I try out the result, it's weird that on every key I type, instead of appending, it's overwritten instead.

I was expecting **setUserText(`${userText}${key}`);** to have new typed key append to current state and set as a new state but instead, it's forgetting the old state and rewriting with the new state.

Was it really the correct way that we should register and deregister event on every re-render?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The best way to go about such scenarios is to see what you are doing in the event handler.

If you are simply setting `state` using previous `state`, it's best to use the callback pattern and register the event listeners only on *initial* mount.

If you do not use the [callback pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), the listeners reference along with its lexical scope is being used by the event listener but a new function is created with updated closure on each render; hence in the handler you will not be able to access the updated state

```
const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");
const handleUserKeyPress = useCallback(event => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;
    if(keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)){
        setUserText(prevUserText => `${prevUserText}${key}`);
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
}, [handleUserKeyPress]);

  return (
      <div>
          <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
          <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
      </div>
  );
```

Comment: but this will create a new bound function every keypress. if your focus is perfromance a local state variable is much better

Comment: @di3 If you use `useCallback` to define the function with empty dependency array, you won't have that issue as well

Comment: if `handleUserKeyPress` isn't pulled inside `useEffect`, then it's an external dependency and should be explicit: `useEffect(..., [handleUserKeyPress])`

Comment: @Aprillion thats not true, empty array is specially used for mount/unmount check. the intention is to call it only once.

Comment: if the intention is to call it once, then don't create a new unused function in every render and pull it inside useEffect. your solution would create a bug if you add dependencies to 2nd argument of useCallback because the useEffect is missing its own dependency

Comment: I see the important is to use `prevUserText ` to reference the previous state of `userText`. what if I need to access multiple states? How can I get access to all of the previous state?

Comment: How can we get previous state if we're using `useReducer` instead of `useState` ?

Comment: this is able to change state using the previous state, but how would you be able to access the current state?

Comment: @JeremyNelson, if by accessing current state, you mean accessing the updated state, you can either do it using a new useEffect or since you already have the value to be returned from within setUserText, you can use it before returning from its callback

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri this is exactly what i was looking for! <3
Can somebody proficient with hooks explain in a few words when to pass a parameter to the effect itself ( the first arg of useEffect) and when not to? It seems to work fine in both cases when i log a state update in a didupdate-manner, but i'm not clear on whether this goes for more complex cases.

Comment: @tractatusviii I think this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902

Comment: @Eesa You always have the previous state available to you in the reducer function supplied to `useReducer`. The `prevState` callback function is a workaround for `useState`.

Comment: I had the same problem and I had been struggling with it for a long time. but your solution saved my day :)

Comment: If I have one more state for example: const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false); and I want to use it in handleUserKeyPress I need to add "visible" to useCallback's dependencies array: [visible]. But in this case keydown listeners will be resubscribed on every change of "visible". Can we avoid it?

Answer (score 78):

## Issue

> [...] on each and every re-render, events will keep registering and deregistering every time and I simply don't think it is the right way to go about it.

You are right. It doesn't make sense to restart event handling inside `useEffect` on *every* render.

> [...] empty array as the second argument, letting the component to only run the effect once [...] it's weird that on every key I type, instead of appending, it's overwritten instead.

This is an issue with [stale closure values](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function).

Reason: Used functions inside `useEffect` should be [part of the dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies). You set nothing as dependency (`[]`), but still call `handleUserKeyPress`, which itself reads `userText` state.

## Solutions

### 0. `useEffectEvent` (beta)

***Update***: React developers proposed an [RFC](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md) including new `useEvent` Hook ([name and functionality have changed](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/25881) slightly since) to solve this exact type of event-related problem with dependencies.

Until then, there are alternatives depending on your use case:

### 1. State updater function

```
setUserText(prev => `${prev}${key}`);
```

✔ least invasive approach
✖ only access to own previous state, not other state Hooks

```js
const App = () => {
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
      const { key, keyCode } = event;

      if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
        setUserText(prev => `${prev}${key}`); // use updater function here
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, []); // still no dependencies

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef } = React</script>
```

### 2. `useRef` / mutable refs

```
const cbRef = useRef(handleUserKeyPress);
useEffect(() => { cbRef.current = handleUserKeyPress; }); // update each render
useEffect(() => {
    const cb = e => cbRef.current(e); // then use most recent cb value
    window.addEventListener("keydown", cb);
    return () => { window.removeEventListener("keydown", cb) };
}, []);
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");

  const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;

    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      setUserText(`${userText}${key}`);
    }
  };

  const cbRef = useRef(handleUserKeyPress);

  useEffect(() => {
    cbRef.current = handleUserKeyPress;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const cb = e => cbRef.current(e);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", cb);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", cb);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } = React</script>
```

✔ can be used for callbacks/event handlers that shall not trigger re-renders via data flow
✔ no need to manage dependencies
✖ more imperative approach
✖ only recommended as last option by React docs

Take a look at these links for further info: [1](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) [2](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-read-an-often-changing-value-from-usecallback) [3](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often)

### 3. `useReducer` - ["cheat mode"](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#why-usereducer-is-the-cheat-mode-of-hooks)

We can switch to `useReducer` and have access to current state/props - with similar API to `useState`.

##### Variant 2a: logic inside reducer function

```
const [userText, handleUserKeyPress] = useReducer((state, event) => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;
    // isUpperCase is always the most recent state (no stale closure value)
    return `${state}${isUpperCase ? key.toUpperCase() : key}`;  
}, "");
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isUpperCase, setUpperCase] = useState(false);
  const [userText, handleUserKeyPress] = useReducer((state, event) => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;
    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      // isUpperCase is always the most recent state (no stale closure)
      return `${state}${isUpperCase ? key.toUpperCase() : key}`;
    }
  }, "");

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
      <button style={{ width: "150px" }} onClick={() => setUpperCase(b => !b)}>
        {isUpperCase ? "Disable" : "Enable"} Upper Case
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef } = React</script>
```

##### Variant 2b: logic outside reducer function - similar to `useState` updater function

```
const [userText, setUserText] = useReducer((state, action) =>
      typeof action === "function" ? action(state, isUpperCase) : action, "");
// ...
setUserText((prevState, isUpper) => `${prevState}${isUpper ? 
  key.toUpperCase() : key}`);
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isUpperCase, setUpperCase] = useState(false);
  const [userText, setUserText] = useReducer(
    (state, action) =>
      typeof action === "function" ? action(state, isUpperCase) : action,
    ""
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
      const { key, keyCode } = event;
      if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
        setUserText(
          (prevState, isUpper) =>
            `${prevState}${isUpper ? key.toUpperCase() : key}`
        );
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
      <button style={{ width: "150px" }} onClick={() => setUpperCase(b => !b)}>
        {isUpperCase ? "Disable" : "Enable"} Upper Case
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef } = React</script>
```

✔ no need to manage dependencies
✔ access multiple states and props
✔ same API as `useState`
✔ extendable to more complex cases/reducers
✖ slightly less performance due to inline reducer ([kinda neglectable](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#why-usereducer-is-the-cheat-mode-of-hooks))
✖ slightly increased complexity of reducer

## Inappropriate solutions

### `useCallback`

While it can be applied in various ways, `useCallback` is not suitable *for this particular question case*.

Reason: Due to the added dependencies - `userText` here -, the event listener will be re-started on *every* key press, in best case being not performant, or worse causing inconsistencies.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");

  const handleUserKeyPress = useCallback(
    event => {
      const { key, keyCode } = event;

      if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
        setUserText(`${userText}${key}`);
      }
    },
    [userText]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleUserKeyPress]); // we rely directly on handler, indirectly on userText

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } = React</script>
```

### Declare handler function inside `useEffect`

Declaring the event [handler function directly inside `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) has more or less the same issues as `useCallback`, latter just causes a bit more indirection of dependencies.

In other words: Instead of adding an additional layer of dependencies via `useCallback`, we put the function directly inside `useEffect` - but all the dependencies still need to be set, causing frequent handler changes.

In fact, if you move `handleUserKeyPress` inside `useEffect`, ESLint exhaustive deps rule will tell you, what exact canonical dependencies are missing (`userText`), if not specified.

```js
const App =() => {
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
      const { key, keyCode } = event;

      if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
        setUserText(`${userText}${key}`);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, [userText]); // ESLint will yell here, if `userText` is missing

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef } = React</script>
```

Comment: This is starting to look more and more like an overlooked design flaw in hooks

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 indeed you might be right! There is a new RFC for event-related hooks (updated answer)

Comment: Thank goodness, we need this. EDIT: You have a link btw? I'd like to take a peek.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md

Answer (score 20):

new answer:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handlekeydownEvent(event) {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;
    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      setUserText(prevUserText => `${prevUserText}${key}`);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('keyup', handlekeydownEvent)
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', handlekeydownEvent)
  }
}, [])
```

when using `setUserText`, pass the function as the argument instead of the object, the `prevUserText` will be always the newest state.

---

old answer:

try this, it works same as your original code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handlekeydownEvent(event) {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;
    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      setUserText(`${userText}${key}`);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('keyup', handlekeydownEvent)
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', handlekeydownEvent)
  }
}, [userText])
```

because in your `useEffect()` method, it depends on the `userText` variable but you don't put it inside the second argument, else the `userText` will always be bound to the initial value `''` with argument `[]`.

you don't need to do like this, just want to let you know why your second solution doesn't work.

Comment: By adding `[userText]` is exactly the same as without second argument, right? Reason is I only have `userText` in the above example, and without second argument simply means re-rerender on every props/state changes, I don't see how it answer my question. **P/S: ** I'm not the downvoter, thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: hey @Isaac , yep, it is same as without second argument, I just want to let you know why your second solution doesn't work, because your second solution `useEffect()` depend on the `userText` variable but you didn't put inside the second arguments.

Comment: But by adding in `[userText]`, it also means register and deregister the event on every re-render right?

Comment: exactly! that why I say it is same with your first solution.

Comment: haha yeap I get the idea, but point is, I'm feeling it's inefficient, because I feel an event shouldn't be `register` and `deregister` on every re-render, but instead should be like the classic `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`, where they only register once, if you get my point?

Comment: While your current recommendation is having register event at `componentDidUpdate`, which isn't the same way we done things right?

Comment: got what you mean, if you really want to register it only one time in this example, then you need to use `useRef`, just as @Maaz Syed Adeeb 's answer.

Comment: I've just upvoted your answer for going thru this with me. Wondering based on your understanding, is `useRef` a more recommended way in comparison with di3's answer above?

Comment: @Isaac in my understanding, yes.

Comment: hey @Isaac now I have the newer understanding, you don't need `useRef` or `useCallback` neither, just `useState` and `useEffect`, see my new answer.

Answer (score 4):

For your use case, `useEffect` needs a dependency array to track changes and based on the dependency it can determine whether to re-render or not. It is always advised to pass a dependency array to `useEffect`. Kindly see the code below:

I have introduced `useCallback` hook.

```
const { useCallback, useState, useEffect } = React;

  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");

  const handleUserKeyPress = useCallback(event => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;

    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      setUserText(prevUserText => `${prevUserText}${key}`);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleUserKeyPress]);

  return (
    <div>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Edit q98jov5kvq]

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it's exactly the same as `[userText]` or without second argument. Basically we put a `console.log` inside `useEffect`, we will see that the logging is firing every re-render, which also means, `addEventListender` is running every re-render

Comment: I want to believe that is an expected behaviour. I updated my answer.

Comment: On your sandbox, you've put a statement `console.log('>');` within `useEffect` hooks, and by using your updated code, it's still logging everytime, which also means the events are still registering on every re-render

Comment: No, for `addEventListener` it doesn't work that way. It is not called multiple times. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners

Comment: but because of `return () => {window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress)}`, on every re-render, the component will register and deregister

Comment: We can put another console log inside `return () => { console.log('im removing!')}` and can see that on every keystroke, event will be deregister and re-register

Comment: Exactly the behaviour that I wished for, but you can observe it @ https://codesandbox.io/s/n5j7qy051j

Comment: @Isaac it wouldn't re-register on every *render*, only on every change of `userText` (so on most, but not all, keystrokes)

Comment: @Aprillion: I understand your point but dont think this solution is what I'm truly looking for. You may have a look at the accepted answer instead

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a way to keep track of the previous state. `useState` helps you keep track of the current state only. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state), there is a way to access the old state, by using another hook.

```
const prevRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  prevRef.current = userText;
});
```

I've updated your example to use this. And it works out.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("");
  const prevRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    prevRef.current = userText;
  });

  const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;

    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      setUserText(`${prevRef.current}${key}`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is working but if you are registering `BackHandler` event, make sure to `return true` in your `handleBackPress` function, e.g:

```
const handleBackPress= useCallback(() => {
   // do some action and return true or if you do not
   // want the user to go back, return false instead
   return true;
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPress);
    return () =>
       BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPress);
  }, [handleBackPress]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the useRef solution based on @ford04's answer and moved to custom hook. I like it most because it doesn't require adding any manual dependencies and allows to hide all the complexity in the custom hook.

```
const useEvent = (eventName, eventHandler) => {
  const cbRef = useRef(eventHandler)

  useEffect(() => {
    cbRef.current = eventHandler
  }) // update after each render

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("+++ subscribe")
    const cb = (e) => cbRef.current(e) // then use most recent cb value
    window.addEventListener(eventName, cb)
    return () => {
      console.log("--- unsubscribe")
      window.removeEventListener(eventName, cb)
    }
  }, [eventName])
  return
}
```

Usage in App:

```
function App() {
  const [isUpperCase, setUpperCase] = useState(false)
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState("")

  const handleUserKeyPress = (event) => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event
    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      const displayKey = isUpperCase ? key.toUpperCase() : key
      const newText = userText + displayKey
      setUserText(newText)
    }
  }
  useEvent("keydown", handleUserKeyPress)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={isUpperCase}
          onChange={() => setUpperCase(!isUpperCase)}
        />
        Upper Case
      </label>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit]

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use `useCallback` or similar functionality if you are not directly rendering the element you want to attach the listener to. @ford04' answer extensively covers the cases here.

However, **if you are rendering the element yourself**, adding the event directly to the target element not only is cleaner but it also just works whether you use `useCallback` or not!

```
const elementRef = useRef(null);

...

return (
  <div ref={elementRef} onKeyDown={handleUserKeyPress}>
  ...
```

In this case, React will automatically reattach the updated function to the element on every re-render.

Answer (score -1):

In the second approach, the `useEffect` is bound only once and hence the `userText` never gets updated. One approach would be to maintain a local variable which gets updated along with the `userText` object on every keypress.

```
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState('');
  let local_text = userText
  const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;

    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      local_text = `${userText}${key}`;
      setUserText(local_text);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
```

Personally I don't like the solution, feels `anti-react` and I think the first method is good enough and is designed to be used that way.

Comment: Do you mind to include some code to demonstrate how to achieve my objective in second method?

Answer (score -1):

you dont have access to the changed useText state. you can comapre it to the prevState. store the state in a variable e.g.: state like so:

```
const App = () => {
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    let state = ''

    const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
      const { key, keyCode } = event;
      if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
        state += `${key}`
        setUserText(state);
      }   
    };  
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);
    };  
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );  
};
```