# how to set react useState in useEffect and in window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 2 state variables, at the page load the program checks to see if there is an available agent and if yes, setDefault state variable is set to true, and then if a language change event is fired and there's an available agent the setStudio is set true, 
however when the conditional rendering is done default is always true, even though I set it to false in the eventListener fires,
can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.

any help would be appreciated.

```
 const Home = ({ t, i18n, history }) => {
     const [defaultStudio, setDefaultStudio] = useState(false);
     const [studio, setStudio] = useState(false);

     useEffect(() => {

       checkForAvailableAgent(LINK_TO_AGENT)
        .then(res => {
          setDefaultStudio(res);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("an error happened.");
        });

        window.addEventListener("langChange", () => {
          if(i18n.language === "en") { 
            checkForAvailableAgent(LINK_TO_AGENT)
             .then(res => {
               setStudio(res);
               setDefaultStudio(false);
            })
          .catch(error => {
             console.log("an error happened.");
          });
        } else {
          setStudio(false);
          setDefaultStudio(false);
        }
      });

     },[defaultStudio, studio, i18n.language]);



    return (
      defaultStudio ? 
       (<Button>Call live</Button>)
       : 
       (<Button>Call</Button>)

     )
    }
```

Comment: The answer here may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565444/how-to-register-event-with-useeffect-hooks

Comment: How do you know your event listener gets triggered ever? I'd suggest add more logging, including event listener entry point.

Comment: Your code looks syntactically incorrect.  Were is your close `}` & `)` missing for your addEventListener, are you not getting errors in your console.  Your indentation is wrong too, correct that it would be more obvious.

Comment: `return ({ defaultStudio ?`  That looks incorrect too, again are you not getting any errors, putting `{` after a `(` is telling the JS engine to start an object literal..  Just do `return defaultStudio ?` instead..

Comment: @Keith, thanks, I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Default is a **protected keyword** in javascript.

```
var default = 1;
SyntaxError: missing variable name
```

It is used to identify a default export module. `export default myComponent;`
Renaming your variable should solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must be use **removeEventListener**

try this:

```
const handleUserlangChange = useCallback(event => {
    // do somethings
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('langChange', handleUserlangChange);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('langChange', handleUserlangChange);
    };

},[default, studio, i18n.language]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it, just for future reference, I had to take out [default, studio, i18n.language] from the useEffect.