# What if an rxjs Observable Depends on React State?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks, observable, use-effect

Subscribing react state to an [rxjs Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) is simple:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as r from 'rxjs'
import * as ro from 'rxjs/operators'

const obs$: r.Observable<number> = ...

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = obs$.subscribe(setCount)
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
  }, [])
  return (...)
}
```

But what if my `Observable` depends on some react state and I don't want to re-subscribe every time it changes?

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [otherCount, setOtherCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = obs$.pipe(
      ro.map(c => c + otherCount),
    ).subscribe(setCount)
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
  }, [otherCount]) // this will resubscribe every time `otherCount` changes
  return (...)
}
```

What if `obs$` does something expensive every time it starts? Is there a safe way to do something like this without resubscribing every time `otherCount` changes?

Comment: Depending how exactly you want it to work, state changes could be made an observable, and then two of them could be combined with "zip".

Answer (score 1):

The deeper issue here is event handling with react `useEffect` - [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565444/how-to-register-event-with-useeffect-hooks)

I ended up going with this option from [this answer for that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62005831)

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [otherCount, setOtherCount] = useState(0)
  const otherCountRef = useRef(otherCount)
  useEffect(() => {
    otherCountRef.current = otherCount
  }, [otherCount])
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = obs$.pipe(
      ro.map(c => c + otherCountRef.current),
    ).subscribe(setCount)
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
  }, [])
  return (...)
}
```