# Weird behavior with setState in React: State never saving

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a project where I need to capture all user inputs and concat all characters into a string state variable. My current code can capture all inputs, however the state variable is always one char. Ex: User types "a" and state is set to "A". Then user types "b", and state is set to "B". Intended behavior is state to be set to "AB".

Current code:

```
const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState<string>("");
useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (e.code === "Enter") {
            console.log("Pressed enter");
        } else if (e.code === "Backspace") {
            console.log("Pressed backspace");
        } else {
            const key = e.key.toUpperCase();
            if (key.length === 1 && key >= "A" && key <= "Z") {
                setCurrentGuess(`${currentGuess}${key}`);
            }
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keyup", listener);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("keyup", listener);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: This happens because your event listener (created once) only sees the `currentGuess` state as it had been (blank) when it was created. The easiest way around is to add `currentGuess` as a dependency to `useEffect`, but it doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to register event with useEffect hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565444/how-to-register-event-with-useeffect-hooks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `currentGuess` doesn't change in the listener's scope, just change the set:

```js
...
setCurrentGuess((previousGuess) => `${previousGuess}${key}`);
...
```

this will allow to use the previously set guess.

---

More on this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).