# setState placed in an event listener not updating the state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having a weird issue where a setState is not setting the state correctly and I can't figure out why is this happening. I have a component that has a useState `batch` property and I have created an event listener in the useEffect that listens for the `test` event and adds it to the `batch` state property.

Unfortunately, it seems that even if I emit a couple of test events, they don't get saved in the batch property correctly. I imagine the fact that the setState is in an event listener has something to do with this

```
const AnalyticsProvider= ({ children }) => {
    const [batch, setBatch] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Doorman.test((event) => setBatch((previousBatch) => [...previousBatch, event]));
    }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use effect you have there will only run on the first render. Thus making the listener only run on the first render. Move it outside of the useEffect and see if that works.

Comment: Wouldn't it register it on the first render, meaning that on every subsequent render it would already be registered?

Comment: The listener isn't bound to anything other than running on every re-render of the component.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how it should look like please?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565444/how-to-register-event-with-useeffect-hooks) This binds an event to the window rather than having it only running the event once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to clean up the listner for the component to rerender.  Also the useEffect needs to fire more often than mount.

Probably something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  Doorman.test((event) => setShouldShowUpgradeDialog((previousBatch) => 
    [...previousBatch, event]));
  return () => Remove Doorman.test // This is pseudocode
))
```

You likely want to create or use lodash's debounce function to limit this.