# State variable gives old value when the function is added to a event listener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the below given react.js code, I am fetching some data on page load. I have used `arePostsLoading` state variable to track if the data is loaded or not. I have also added a function `handleScroll` which tracks scrolling and run another function `loadMorePosts` when the page is scrolled to the end of the page. Now I am using console.log to check the value of `arePostsLoading` inside the `loadMorePosts` function.

Now when the page is loading, `arePostsLoading` is initally true. Then the content is loaded and value is set to false. I can confirm the value is set to false because when the value of the variable is false, the content loaded is visible on the page and the loading spinner is hidden. After this, I scroll the page to bottom to trigger the `loadMorePosts` function which just console.log's the `arePostsLoading` value(for testing). The logged value I was getting was `true` which was not the current value of the `arePostsLoading`. This confused me because the current value of `arePostsLoading` should be false(which is confirmed by the loaded content and react dev tools).

After a lot of debugging I found out the issue, the function I was adding to the event listener at the start of the page load was containing the old value of `arePostsLoading`. I fixed this by adding `arePostsLoading` as dependency so that a new event listener is created when the `arePostsLoading` value is changed.

The issue is fixed but I can't understand why It works this way. I am just passing the function to the event listener not the value of the `arePostsLoading`, so why is it taking the old value. Also, if I add another function inside `loadMorePosts` and then console.log the value will it give the new value(example below: eg)?

Sorry, for the long description of the question. I just wanted it to be very clear to understand.

Code:

```
const [arePostsLoading, setArePostsLoading] = useState(true);
  //load posts
  const getAllPosts = async (newPageNo, newPageSize) => {
  setArePostsLoading(true);
  const [data, error] = await sendRequest(
    //...fetch data code
  );
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    handleError(error);
    return;
  }
  setArePostsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // setArePostsLoading(true);
    getAllPosts(1, pageSize);
  },[]);

    //Load more posts
    const loadMorePosts = () => {
      const nextPageNo = pageData.pageNo + 1;
      if (arePostsLoading) {
        getAllPosts(nextPageNo, pageSize);
      }
    };

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      const scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
      const clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight + 2;
      const scrollTop =
        window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      // Check if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page
      if (scrollHeight - scrollTop < clientHeight) {
        // Perform your action here, such as loading more content
        console.log("End of page reached!");
        loadMorePosts();
      }
    }

    // Attach the scroll event listener to the window object
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
  // }, [arePostsLoading]);  // fix added later


  /////////////////////
  //eg 1 : example code
  function loadMorePosts(){
    test1();
  }
  function test1(){
    console.log(arePostsLoading);
  }
```

Comment: In your code example, I don't see any call to `getAllPosts` so there is no code changing the value of `arePostsLoading`. Did you forget to add the code related to this part in your example?

Comment: @ThibaultFriedrich, Apologies, I missed to add that part of the code. I have added it now.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your code, the `getAllPosts()` function is created anew every time your component is rendered.  And the `handleScroll()` function is created when `useEffect()`, and will record the state of the component mount; hence in the handler you will not be able to access the updated state.

You should put your window listener callback function in a `useCallback()` hook.  Also as you realized there is no reason to put the state variable in the dependencies.

See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565444/how-to-register-event-with-useeffect-hooks) for an example

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is fixed but I can't understand why It works this way. I am
> just passing the function to the event listener not the value of the
> arePostsLoading, so why is it taking the old value. Also, if I add
> another function inside `loadMorePosts` and then `console.log` the
> value will it give the new value?

This is a Javascript [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

> A **closure** is the combination of a function bundled together
> (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the **lexical
> environment**). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer
> function's scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are
> created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

You close over a copy of the `arePostsLoading` state in the `loadMorePosts` callback function that is closed over in the `handleScroll` callback function that is passed as the scroll event handler.

When you used an empty dependency array you are saying to do this exactly once at the end of the initial render cycle. The `arePostsLoading` value will be whatever it is/was on the initial render cycle and will never be updated.

When you add `arePostsLoading` as an external dependency each time that it updates a *new* copy of `loadMorePosts` is created that closes over the current `arePostsLoading` value, which is closed over in a *new* copy of `handleScroll` and passed as the scroll event listener.

### Suggestion(s)

If `loadMorePosts` is used elsewhere in the component then you should memoize the function with `useCallback` and specify `arePostsLoading` and the page values as dependencies so they are properly enclosed and include `loadMorePosts` in the `useEffect` hook's dependency.

```js
const [arePostsLoading, setArePostsLoading] = useState(true);

const loadMorePosts = React.useCallback(() => {
  const nextPageNo = pageData.pageNo + 1;
  if (arePostsLoading) {
    getAllPosts(nextPageNo, pageSize);
  }
}, [arePostsLoading, /* pageData, pageSize /*]);

useEffect(() => {
  function handleScroll() {
    const scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    const clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight + 2;
    const scrollTop =
      window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    // Check if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page
    if (scrollHeight - scrollTop < clientHeight) {
      // Perform your action here, such as loading more content
      loadMorePosts();
    }
  }

  // Attach the scroll event listener to the window object
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

  // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  };
}, [loadMorePosts]);
```

This isn't much work, but it is some work. If you'd prefer to not tear down and remove event listeners and instantiate new listeners all just to capture the current `arePostsLoading` state value you can cache the state into a React ref where the ref's current value can be updated and accessed at any time in the future from within the closure. The ref is closed over, but the value can be mutated.

Basic Example:

```js
const [arePostsLoading, setArePostsLoading] = useState(true);
const arePostsLoadingRef = React.useRef(arePostsLoading);

useEffect(() => {
  arePostsLoadingRef.current = arePostsLoading;
}, [arePostsLoading]);

const loadMorePosts = () => {
  const nextPageNo = pageData.pageNo + 1;
  if (arePostsLoadingRef.current) {
    getAllPosts(nextPageNo, pageSize);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  function handleScroll() {
    const scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    const clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight + 2;
    const scrollTop =
      window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    // Check if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page
    if (scrollHeight - scrollTop < clientHeight) {
      // Perform your action here, such as loading more content
      loadMorePosts();
    }
  }

  // Attach the scroll event listener to the window object
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

  // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  };
}, []);
```