Clicking on antd select menu options making current of ref null
I am developing feature for opening a filter box when click on button and i need to close it when clicked outside. For this I have used useRef hook and i am using antd ui elements like select and datepicker. Everything is working fine but when i click on menu opened by select or datepicker component and select any option. It is getting considered as hanleclciked outside but the component is inside my ref. I am adding code and screenshots for refernce.
import { Card, Select } from "antd";
import { FilterObject, PaymentStatus } from "../../helpers/types";
import { capitalizeString } from "../../helpers/functions";
import { CommonDatePicker } from "../datePicker/CommonDatePicker";
import { CommonButton } from "..";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { filterIcon } from "../../../finance/assets";
import { FILTERS } from "../../helpers/constants";

export const Filters = () => {
  // useStates
  const [showFilters, setShowFilters] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState<FilterObject>({
    status: "",
    startDate: "",
    endDate: "",
  });

  // useRef
  const filterRef = useRef<any>(null);

  // useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  });

  //   funticons
  const handleClickOutside = (event: any) => {
    if (filterRef.current && !filterRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      setShowFilters(false);
    }
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (name: string, value: string) => {
    const tempFilters: FilterObject = { ...filters };
    if (name === FILTERS.status) {
      tempFilters.status = value;
    }
    console.log(tempFilters);

    setFilters(tempFilters);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={filterRef}>
      {showFilters && (
        <Card className="absolute top-[4.8rem] right-[10rem] text-[#232425] text-[14px] z-50 w-[21rem] bg-[#FFFFFF]">
          <p className="font-bold text-lg">Filter By</p>
          <hr className="mt-4" />
          <div className="mt-4">
            <p>Select Status</p>
            <Select
              className="w-full mt-2"
              onChange={(e: string) => {
                handleFilterChange(FILTERS.status, e);
              }}
              defaultValue="Select Status"
              options={[
                {
                  value: PaymentStatus.approved,
                  label: capitalizeString(PaymentStatus.approved),
                },
                {
                  value: PaymentStatus.pending,
                  label: capitalizeString(PaymentStatus.pending),
                },
                {
                  value: PaymentStatus.rejected,
                  label: capitalizeString(PaymentStatus.rejected),
                },
              ]}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mt-4">
            <p>From Date</p>
            <CommonDatePicker
              onChange={(e) => {
                console.log(e);
              }}
              inputClass="w-full"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mt-4">
            <p>To Date</p>
            <CommonDatePicker
              onChange={(e: any) => {
                console.log(e);
              }}
              inputClass="w-full"
            />
          </div>

          <CommonButton
            title="Submit"
            onClick={() => {}}
            buttonClass="[&]:w-full [&]:h-[2.2rem]"
          />
        </Card>
      )}
      <img
        className="cursor-pointer"
        src={filterIcon}
        alt=""
        onClick={() => setShowFilters(!showFilters)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};


as i said when i click on approve pending or reject. It is getting considered as outside click

When i click or select filters option, I dont want to consider it as outside click and do not want to close the filter box.

You should use onFocus and onBlur instead

Additionally your useEffect gets executed on each render. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62005831/8724386
